# Characterized by measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

Is there a function that inverse function take a borel set to measurable set, but don’t take a measurable set to measurable set?

Comment: f is a real function.yes Lebesge measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\subseteq \Bbb R$ be a set which is measurable but is not borel __ I think only if you accept Axiom of Choice there's such a set __ and choose $c\in A^c$. Then I think the function
$$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$$
$$(\forall x\in A^c)(f(x)=x)$$
$$f(A)=\{c\}$$
is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I do not want this answer be deleted.